# How to add model object to many to many field in django.1.9 and not get TypeError

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I got:

```
Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField("name", max_length=100)
Entry(models.Model):
    (...)
    authors = models.ManyToMany(Author, blank=true)

def findAuthors(input):
    (...)
    authors = []
    for name in names:
        authors.append(Author.objects.get_or_create(name=name))
    return authors
```

and I'm trying to do:

```
e = Entry.objects.first() #for exmple
authors = findAuthors()
if authors:
    for author in authors:
        e.authors.add(author)
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Author'`
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method returns a tuple, not just the object. You could fix it by changing your code to:

```
authors = []
for name in names:
    author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    authors.append(author)
    return authors
```